# Why is doctrine not selecting all columns from entity?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I believe doctrine should always select all fields for an entity when it queries it. I'm using Kitpages' DataGrid bundle with the following code:

```
    // create query builder
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyApplicationBundle:Application');
    $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a', 'u');
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin('a.created_by', 'u'); // join user info

    $gridConfig = new GridConfig();
    $gridConfig
        ->setCountFieldName('a.id')
        ->addField(new Field('a.name', array('label'=>'col.name', 'sortable' => true, 'filterable'=>true)))
        ->addField(new Field('a.app_type', array('label'=>'col.type', 'sortable' => true, 'filterable'=>true)))
        ->addField(new Field('a.created_by', array(
            'label'=>'col.user',
            'sortable' => true,
            'filterable'=>true,
            'nullIfNotExists'=>true,
            'formatValueCallback' => function($createdBy) {
                if($createdBy instanceof \My\UserBundle\Entity\User)
                    return $createdBy->getName();
            }
        )))
    ;
```

Now I have some entities where created_by is null, and some where it is an id referencing a row in the fos_user table. I should be getting the name value for the entities that actually have a value in createdBy, but I'm getting empty columns in every row of the grid for the creator.

I'm my logs I can see the SQL that doctrine is fetching.

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id0, a0_.name AS name1, a0_.app_type AS app_type2, a0_.public AS public3, a0_.enabled AS enabled4, a0_.likegating AS likegating5, a0_.mobile_optimized AS mobile_optimized6, a0_.share_data AS share_data7, a0_.created_date AS created_date8, a0_.updated_date AS updated_date9 FROM application a0_ LEFT JOIN fos_user f1_ ON a0_.created_by_id = f1_.id LIMIT 15 OFFSET 15
```

It doesn't select `a0_.created_by_id` at all. How do I get the select to include that field? I also tried changing the Field to 'u.name', but it didn't help.

Notice: In addition to changing my code to include the `addSelect('u')` like the accepted answer mentions, I also changed my `'formatValueCallback'` to treat the variable as an array. Like so:

```
'formatValueCallback' => function($createdBy) {
    if(isset($createdBy['name']))
        return $createdBy['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you are not getting u.name even though a relation exists?

Change:

```
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a', 'u');
```

The createQueryBuilder only takes one argument which will be an alias for your application object.  The 'u' is ignored.

To:

```
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
$queryBuilder->addSelect('u');
```

And that will populate your user entity.

a0_.created_by_id does not show up in your select clause because it is used on the join statement to get the linked user object.  created_by_id never actually get's stored in you application object.  After making the above change, you can check the sql and will see a bunch of user attributes are now being selected.

===========================================================

And just for future reference, this is the code that your repository uses to make a query builder:

```
class Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

public function createQueryBuilder($alias)
{
    return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($alias)
        ->from($this->_entityName, $alias);
}
```

Comment: should it not be `$qb->addSelect('u');` rather than `select`, a second `select` statement will overwrite the first.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, I'm now getting the correct sql. It selects all the fields from the "u" aswell. I had to change my formatting callback as the `$createdBy` was actually an array instead of an object. Adding that to my post.